# Add class to current Isotope filter

Tags: jquery-isotope

I'm using the following jQuery to filter Isotope items:

```
    $('#nav a').click(function(){
      var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({ 
        filter: selector,
        animationOptions: {
         duration: 1200,
         easing: 'linear',
         queue: false,

       }
      });
```

Which corresponds with this HTML:

```
<nav id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
            <li><a href="" data-filter=".cat1">Category 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="" data-filter=".cat2">Category 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="" data-filter=".cat3">Category 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="" data-filter=".cat4">Category 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="" data-filter=".cat5">Category 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

I'd like for the current filter link to have a class of "current" when in view. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use addClass and removeClass to your function. You will want to remove the class from all items before you add the class to clear it from whichever item was selected previously.

```
    $('#nav a').click(function(){
      //removes class from all items to "clear" the class from your menu
      $('#nav a').removeClass("current");

      //adds the class to whichever item you clicked
      $(this).addClass("current");

      var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({ 
        filter: selector,
        animationOptions: {
         duration: 1200,
         easing: 'linear',
         queue: false,

       }
      });
});
```